# is the object instanciated

Tags: object, gtk, vala

here is a sample source code of vala for creating a simple GTK application from elementary os website

```
public class Examples.Application : Gtk.Application {
    public Application () {
        Object (
            application_id: "org.valadoc.examples",
            flags: ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE
        );
    }

    protected override void activate () {
        var application_window = new Gtk.ApplicationWindow (this);
        application_window.show_all ();
    }

    public static int main (string[] args) {
        var app = new Application ();
        return app.run (args);
    }
}
```

i dont understand th object in this code? what is it? is it an object ? if its an object so why it has not new keword and not instanciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Object()` you see there in the constructor is a Vala-specific syntax called: [GObject-style construction](https://naaando.gitbooks.io/the-vala-tutorial/content/en/4-object-oriented-programming/gobject-style-construction.html). It allows you to set your properties all at once.

This allows you to work with GObject's so-called "construct properties": properties which can be set during construction (sometimes they can even only exclusively be set during construction).

Comment: why they dont do that in c# or java style ?

Comment: Construct properties are a GObject thing which have existed for a very long time. Vala is mostly made as a wrapper around GObject. Note that except for some cases, nothing prevents you from just initializing your fields like `this.x = x`

Comment: I probably need to read more about GObject, thanks ;)